# Acquiring dataframe from TSI for certain time periods

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

I am trying to pull some data from the TSI for a defined time period using python. I would like to do this with the help of access tokens generated for security purposes. Can you help me with how to start this process.

@ranah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you'll do this will depend on whether or not you want to authenticate a user, a Service principal / application, or via the device code option. Take a look at the Python sample for obtaining an AAD token [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/authenticating-your-python-application-against-azure-active-directory/). If it's a user that will be accessing the data within TSI then the user should be [granted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-authentication-and-authorization#granting-data-access) either the Reader or Contributor role. If the app will be calling the API as itself then you'll grant the AAD app a role on the TSI instance just like you would for the user.
In the sample code, replace the value for the resource URI with "https://api.timeseries.azure.com/" The trailing slash is needed.
Once you have an AAD token you can then make calls to TSI's [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/reference-query-apis) for events, series, aggregates and model metadata.
Useful links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-authentication-and-authorization#service-principal